# Using display in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am new to verilog and I understand it is not a sequential language. So, I wanted to ask is there some way to display results in a module after some execution?Because display should always be inside `initial` block and so there is no way I can use display for debugging purposes. Here is a sample code which may better explain my problem-

```
module A(a,b,c);
    input a,b;
    output c;

    assign c=a&b;

    initial
      $display("%b",c);
endmodule

module testbench11;
   reg a,b;
   wire c;

   A a1(a,b,c);

   initial
      $monitor(,$time,"a=%b,b=%b,c=%b",a,b,c);

   initial
      begin
         #0 a=1'b0;b=1'b0;         
         #3 a=1'b0;b=1'b0; 
         #3 a=1'b0;b=1'b0; 
      end
endmodule
```

So I want to display the result of `c` after every time instance so as to check whether I am getting desired output. It may seem to display results at the end in this case, but in some complex problems I wanted to use `display` for debugging purposes just as I use `printf` in C. Is there some way to do that in verilog?

Comment: Depending on how you code the module, `$display` might or might not work for what you want to do. Your current use of `$monitor` will certainly inform you whenever any of `a`, `b` or `c` (which are linked to those signals of you module) change, which is probably good enough. Without a better example, the exact form of printing that is best is very difficult to determine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because display should always be inside `initial` block and so there is no way I can use display for debugging purposes.

I am not sure where you got this from, it is the same as nearly everything but `assign` in that it must be used inside a block, `intial` or `always`.

To use it to debug inside the module:

```
module A(a,b,c);
  input  a,b;
  output c;

  assign c = a&b;

  always @*
    $display("%b",c);
endmodule
```

It is best to display and check from the top level keeping the module code clean. to use `display` in the testench you can do:

The same format as inside the module:

```
always @* begin
  $display("%b",c);
end
```

Or to know you are displaying after each stimulus step:

```
initial begin
  #0 a=1'b0;b=1'b0;         
  #1 $display("%b",c);

  #3 a=1'b0;b=1'b0; 
  #1 $display("%b",c);

  #3 a=1'b0;b=1'b0; 
  #1 $display("%b",c);
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Verilog/SystemVerilog contains a well organized event queue. All the statements in each and every time stamp executes according to this queue. Following are some of the different display system tasks.

- **$display** executes in **ACTIVE region**, so if there is any non-blocking assignment(which executes in INACTIVE region), it won't be shown by $display. This displays a single output line.
- **$write** also executes in **ACTIVE region**, but an explicit call to newline character(**\n**) is required to insert another line. This system task is generally used when you want to display Multidimensional array using for loop. This is similar to display except (\n) character.
- **$strobe** executes in **MONITOR/POSTPONED region**, that is, at the end of time stamp. Hence the updated value is shown by $strobe.
- **$monitor** displays every time one of its display parameters changes. Only one $monitor per Simulation is to be used. Monitor, as the name suggests, monitors the signals continuously and executes if **any** signal value changes.

For your code, to display at various points, following change of code can be done.

```
    initial
    #5 $display("%b",c);  // display after some arbitrary time.

    initial
    begin
    repeat(5)
    begin 
     wait(c);
     $display("%b",c);  // display after   change in c 5 times.
    end
    end

    initial
    begin
    forever
    begin 
     #1;
     $display("%b",c);  // display c at every timestamp
    end
    end

    always @(c)
    $display("%b",c);  // display after any change in c

    always @(a,b,c)
    $display("%b",c);  // display after any change in a or b or c
```

For displaying at every change, **$monitor** is useful. $display can be used as above but this will make your code messy. Just remember that there must be only **one** $monitor in your code. There is no such limit in $display.

These are just some of the methods, many other are available. Further information can be found out at [this](http://www.vlsiinterviewquestions.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/verilog_queue.jpg)
and [this](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/example/352) links.

Comment: `$strobe` and `$monitor` is in the **monitor event region** in Verilog. IEEE1364-1995 §5.3, IEEE1364-2001 §5.3, & IEEE1364-2005 §11.3. SystemVerilog the region got renamed to **postponed event region**, [IEEE1800-2012] §4.4.  **Inactive event region** for explicit `#0` delay (citation in the same sections as the monitor region)

Comment: @Greg yeah, I have made a mistake here. Just got confused in **Inactive** and **Postponed** region. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for the pointers.